# django model add default columns

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I have to following model:

```
class publication_type(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True,default=None)
```

And I would like to add a few "default" entrys to this model, that I can always refer to without assuming whether they exist yet or not, for example:

```
publication_type.objects.create(id=1,name="article",description="...")
```

Where would be the best position in the django code to position to put this code?

Comment: It looks like [initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/) is what you're after.

Comment: thanks a lot! Can you tell me how I can use these fixtures for my test setups as well`?